# template member function of template class called from template function

Tags: c++, templates, dependent-name

This doesn't compile:

```
template<class X> struct A {
   template<int I> void f() {}
};

template<class T> void g()
{
   A<T> a;
   a.f<3>();  // Compilation fails here (Line 18)
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   g<int>();  // Line 23
}
```

The compiler (gcc) says:

> hhh.cpp: In function 'void g()':
>
> hhh.cpp:18: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
>
> hhh.cpp: In function 'void g() [with T = int]':
>
> hhh.cpp:23:   instantiated from here
>
> hhh.cpp:18: error: invalid use of member (did you forget the '&' ?)

Can anyone explain why this is?  Is there a way to get it to work?

Comment: What does the compiler complain about?

Comment: It works for me. How are you invoking g() ? (and what error are you getting, as others have asked?)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
template<class T> void g()
{
   A<T> a;
   a.template f<3>();  // add `template` keyword here
}
```

According to C++'03 Standard 14.2/4:

> When the name of a member template specialization appears after `.` or `->` in a *postfix*-expression, or after *nested-name-specifier* in a *qualified-id*, and the postfix-expression or qualified-id explicitly depends on a template-parameter (14.6.2), the member template name must be prefixed by the keyword `template`. Otherwise the name is assumed to name a non-template.

Future C++ Standard seems to be still require this keyword according to draft n2857 14.3/4. Some compilers has special mode that allows to compile original code without errors (Comeau compiles it in so called *relaxed mode*).

Comment: This link also explains why: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/keyword_template_qualifier.htm

Comment: well spotted - I'm always forgetting that one. The fact that VC++ lets it past without doesn't help

Comment: Well...  Who woulda thunk it!  I've never seen this syntax before.  Thanks.

Comment: Future standards (C++0x) still require `template` here. Some compilers are just not standard's conforming (VC++).

Comment: Yes, it still there. Found it in draft n2857.

Comment: I tried the code with comeau online compiler, which accepts it even in the strictest settings: What happened is that it apparently optimized away the local object and didn't care. If you call `return a.f<3>();` instead (and make it return something), it will error out too. This looks like a optimizer bug to me.

Comment: Strange to hear that. I've tried Comeau and it gives the error `line 8: error: expected an expression`.

Comment: Notice the weird wording of "explicitly depends". In early pre-standard drafts, names could explicitly and implicitly depend on template arguments. Nowadays, there is no such difference anymore, but the "explictly" is still apparent in some places :)

Comment: Furture Standard will not require it only when the template can be looked up already ("member of the current instantiation"). If you do `template<typename T> struct A { template<typename U> void f(); void g() { this->f<int>(); } };` then it will go fine because `f` is a "member of the current instantiation" (but only in C++0x, not in C++03).