# Cannot refer to a template name nested in a template parameter

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
template <typename Provider>
inline void use()
{
    typedef Provider::Data<int> D;
}
```

Where I'm basically trying to use a template class member 'Data' of some 'Provider' class, applied to 'int', but I get the following errors:

```
util.cpp:5: error: expected init-declarator before '<' token
util.cpp:5: error: expected `,' or `;' before '<' token
```

I'm using GCC 4.3.3 on a Solaris System.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ template member function of template class called from template function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840253/c-template-member-function-of-template-class-called-from-template-function)

Comment: @Kirill: I think this one is unique in that it requires both `typename` and `template`. (I struggled for a while with how to explain this using the same code and I'm not satisfied.)

Comment: @sbi, yes, this is not exact the same, but very similar question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
typedef typename Provider::template Data<int> D;
```

The problem is that, when the compilers parses `use()` for the first time, it doesn't know `Provider`, so it doesn't know what `Provider::Data` refers to. It could be a static data member, the name of a member function or something else. That's why you have to put the `typename` in.
The additional `template` is necessary whenever the nested name is the name of a template. If it was something else, then `Data < ...` could be a comparison.

Answer (score 8):

You need a `typename` and a `template`:

```
template <typename Provider>
inline void use()
{
    typedef typename Provider::template Data<int> D;
}
```