# Why does this small C++ program not compile using G++?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, g++

The following code will not compile with G++ 4.5 or 4.6 (snapshot). It will compile with the Digital Mars Compiler 8.42n.

```
template <int I>
struct Foo {
  template <int J>
  void bar(int x) {}
};

template <int I>
void test()
{
  Foo<I> a;
  a.bar<8>(9);
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  test<0>();
  return 0;
}
```

The error message is:

```
bugbody.cpp: In function 'void test() [with int I = 0]':
bugbody.cpp:16:11:   instantiated from here
bugbody.cpp:11:3: error: invalid operands of types '<unresolved overloaded function type>' and 'int' to binary 'operator<'
```

Is the program valid C++?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ template member function of template class called from template function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840253/c-template-member-function-of-template-class-called-from-template-function)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put "template" and "typename" on dependent names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-template-and-typename-on-dependent-names)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Since the `bar` in `a.bar` is a *dependent name*, the compiler doesn’t know that it’s a template. You need to specify this, otherwise the compiler interprets the subsequent `<…>` as binary comparison operators:

```
a.template bar<8>(9);
```

The compiler behaves correctly.

The reason for this behaviour lies in specialisation. Imagine that you have specialised the `Foo` class for some value:

```
template <>
struct Foo<0> {
    int bar;
};
```

Now your original code would compile, but it would mean something completely different. In the first parsing pass, the compiler doesn’t yet know which specialisation of `Foo` you’re using here so it needs to disambiguate between the two possible usages of `a.bar`; hence the keyword `template` to show the compiler that the subsequent `<…>` are template arguments.

Comment: Thanks, and a nice answer; I clearly need to hit the books. How does your specialisation allow the original `a.bar<8>(9)` to work? Is it now the method `bar`, or int `bar` which is referenced?

Comment: Oh my! It sees the `<` and `>` as less than and greater than operators! With your specialisation, it sees it as: `(a.bar) < (8 > 9)`

Comment: @user643722 Actually, it’s `(a.bar < 8) > 9` (operators are left associative). But yes, that’s it.