# template parameter as variable

Tags: c++, templates, variables

Is there any way to use a template parameter as a variable?
for example if I have a function

```
template<int dim>
void DomainGrid<dim>::getData(Data data_, int field_dim)
{
    int size_ = field_dim *dim; // Compiler Error Here
    for(int i =0; i<size_; ++i)
       std::cout<<data_[i]<<std::endl;
}
```

Can I get a similar functionality? Compiling this function produces an error at

```
invalid use of member (did you forget the ‘&’ ?)
```

the error appears regardless of whether the function is called or not

Which I guess is because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840253/c-template-member-function-of-template-class-called-from-template-function) problem...

Comment: What's the definition of `DomainGrid`? Chances are you shouldn't be saying `<dim>` twice.

Comment: thanks for your replies.....
yes you are right... but in a different context
there is a function field_dim(). I actually wanted to use a member field_dim_. 
The mistake just escaped my eyes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename either the template parameter or the member function?

That seems like the simplest, most straightforward solution. Whenever multiple symbols have the same name, you risk name clashes. So don't use the same name for multiple symbols in such cases.

(This is assuming you have a member function `dim()`. I assume so based on the error message, but it might have been useful information to actually include in the question.)

Answer (score 2):

```
int size_ = field_dim *dim; // Compiler Error Here
```

This is perfectly fine. This cannot be an error.

The real problem is not in the code which you've posted here. So post the definition of `DomainGrid` and the complete error messages.

Comment: @Als: Based on the post and the information given, I think its an answer. It tells him to look for the real problem which is not in the code posted.

Comment: @Als, we have a downvote button if you don't think the answer is useful.

Comment: @Als: Well, maybe you should use it more often then. ;) The downvote button is there for a reason. ;)

Comment: I am deleting some of my comments because certain modifications were made to the answer later on, which make my comments feel unwarranted.

Comment: @Als: If the second sentence which starts with *`The real problem is not...`* makes your comment unwarranted, then it was unwarranted before as well, because there is nothing in that sentence which adds anything new, except that its a repetition of the first sentence, as the first sentence pretty much says that the problem isn't in that line which OP thinks, causes the error.