# Compilation failure for templated member of templated class. VC++ works but G++ fails

Tags: c++

The following code compiles fine under Visual C++ 2010, but not under GCC 4.6 from the Android NDK r8b.

```
template<typename A>
struct foo
{
    template<typename B>
    B method()
    {
        return B();
    }
};

template<typename A>
struct bar
{
    bar()
    {
        f_.method<int>(); // error here
    }

private:
    foo<A> f_;
};
```

The error GCC gives is

```
error : expected primary-expression before 'int'
error : expected ';' before 'int'
```

for the marked line. For the life of me I can't figure out whats wrong.

Comment: duplicated from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840253/c-template-member-function-of-template-class-called-from-template-function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GCC is correct, since `f_` is of type `foo<A>` which depends on the template parameter `A`, you need to qualify the call to `method` with the `template` keyword:

```
f_.template method<int>();  // This will work
```

Comment: Ah yes of course. Thanks, i always confuse when to use that qualifier.