# How to call a template member function?

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ template member function of template class called from template function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840253/c-template-member-function-of-template-class-called-from-template-function)

```
template<class T1>
class A 
{
public:
    template<class T0>
    void foo() const {}
};

template<class T0,class T1>
void bar( const A<T1>& b )
{
    b.foo<T0>();  // This throws " expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token"
}
```

I can change it to

```
b->A<T1>::template foo<T0>();
```

which compiles fine. However I can also change it to

```
b.A<T1>::template foo<T0>();
```

which compiles fine too. eh?

How does one correctly call the template member function in the sense of the original code?

Comment: Do we know what the two statements that actually compile mean? In this "cooked down" example they compile, but in my real program this does not compile.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Just found it:

According to C++'03 Standard 14.2/4:

> When the name of a member template specialization appears after `.` or
>   `->` in a postfix-expression, or after nested-name-specifier in a qualified-id, and the postfix-expression or qualified-id explicitly depends on a template-parameter (14.6.2), the member template name must be prefixed by the keyword `template`. Otherwise the name is assumed to name a non-template.

Correct code is:

```
b.template foo<T0>();
```

Comment: And this is done for the same reason and in conditions similar to when `typename` is necessary.

Answer (score 14):

you can call the function this way:

```
b.template foo<T0>();
```