# C++: call non-templated functions of a templated class

Tags: c++, function, class, templates

Is it somehow possible to have callable, non-templated functions in a templated class? Like so:

```
template<typename T>
class Object
{
public:
  static int loadInfo() { return 0;}
  // more code
};
```

I'd like to write, e.g.:

```
Object::loadInfo();
```

instead of

```
Object<int8_t>::loadInfo();
```

It's not virtually important, would just be some 'syntactic sugar'. A bit more background: the function I am thinking of would load some data from disk upon which the program decides which templated version of the object it has to use. ATM it looks like this:

```
auto usewhat=Object<char>::loadInfo();   // this line feels so wrong
if(usewhat == 0) {
  Object<int8_t> o;
  o.doSomething();
}else if(usewhat == 1){
  Object<int32_t> o;
  o.doSomething();
}else{
  Object<int64_t> o;
  o.doSomething();
}
```

The only possibilities I can think of atm are 1) using a non-template base class of a different name (say, "BaseObject") or 2) using another class with a different name (say, "InfoObject") ... but both possibilities do not seem too appealing.

Comment: You can use typedefs to create template specializations.

Comment: My 2cts: this should be a free function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676190/how-to-call-a-template-member-function might be related.

Comment: Move `loadInfo` into a class `ObjectBase` and derive `Object<T>` from `ObjectBase`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make `loadInfo` a free function (maybe with a different name like `loadObjectInfo` or whatever makes sense to indicate the semantic relationship with `Object`).

Even though it is a `static` function and does not depend on a particular instance of `Object`, it still depends on `Object`'s template parameters: The function may use `T`, even though in your case it obviously doesn't. This means that the compiler will generate new code for each `Object<T>::loadInfo` with different `T`'s, meaning slower builds and potentially larger binaries. Also, you cannot implement the function in a cpp file.

If you have a copy of Scott Meyers' Effective C++ (3rd Edition) available, you might want to look up Item 44 ("Factor parameter-independent code out of templates").

Comment: So, the answer to my question is "no." Bummer. Seems this could be a nice addition to the C++ standard. Anyway, selected this answer because of hint to relevant chapter in Meyers' book. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but you can use a `typedef` :

```
typdef Object<int8_t> MyObject;
MyObject::loadInfo();
```

Answer (score 1):

If the function can be moved out of the class, do it.

If it cannot be moved out of the class, but does not depend on T, your class is too fat and should be split.

```
class ObjectBase {
  // stuff that doesn't depend on T
  static int loadInfo();
};

template <typename T>
class Object : public ObjectBase {
  // more stuff
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I suppose there is no **portable** way of calling functions of template class without specifying template. I also suggest keeping your code portable as much as possible because it will likely help you in the future (with other compiler of with another version of compiler you currently use).