# LNK2005 for non-templated function when explicitly instantiating templated functions of the class

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to follow the document: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#separate-template-fn-defn-from-decl
It worked well for a class template, but now I need to apply it for a regular class with both function templates and regular ones. Unfortunately linker does not like it.

**asset_registry.h**

```
class ENGINE_API asset_registry
{
public:
   
  asset_registry();

  bool is_valid(int id) const;

  template<typename T>
  bool add(T* object);
}
```

**asset_registry.cpp**

```
asset_registry::asset_registry()
{
  ...
}

bool asset_registry::is_valid(int id) const
{
  ...
}

template<typename T>
bool asset_registry::add(T* object)
{
  ...
}
```

**asset_registry_inst.cpp**

```
#include "asset_registry.cpp"

#include "mesh.h"
#include "texture.h"

template bool asset_registry::add<mesh>(mesh* object);
template bool asset_registry::add<texture>(texture* object);
```

**Linker result**

```
asset_registry_inst.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __cdecl asset_registry::asset_registry(void)" (??0asset_registry@@QEAA@XZ) already defined in asset_registry.obj

asset_registry_inst.obj : error LNK2005: "public: bool __cdecl asset_registry::is_valid(int)const " (?is_valid@asset_registry@@QEBA_NH@Z) already defined in asset_registry.obj
```

Please note that there is no error for `add` function template.

I understand that all regular member functions are compiled in the **asset_registry.cpp**.

**Q1.** Why did compiler create them once again in the **asset_registry_inst.cpp** file?

**Edit:** Ok, I just realized that it is because of the `#include "asset_registry.cpp"`

**Q2.** How to prevent it from creating duplicates?

I checked [C++: call non-templated functions of a templated class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26844619/c-call-non-templated-functions-of-a-templated-class)
But the author uses template class.

I also checked Scott Meyers' Effective C++ (3rd Edition) Item 44 ("Factor parameter-independent code out of templates").
I tried with the base class for non-template code but the result is the same.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Move `template<typename T> bool asset_registry::add(T* object)` into a separate `.h` file and `#include` that instead

Comment: Attempts to do anything other than defining the template in the header file will inevitably end in tears.

Comment: Part of what you've smashed up against is [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: @PaulSanders That worked, thank you!