# call static template method of template class with class as parameter

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates

There is nothing wrong with `static` methods of template classes having (i) templates and (ii) the class itself as a parameter, is there? Consider the class

```
template<class Projection>
struct FrameData {
    // ...
    template <bool devPtr>
    static void allocate(FrameData<Projection> &data) {
        // ... do allocations ...
    }

}
```

This is declared in the header of file `A`.  Elsewhere in the world, I have something like

```
template <class Projection>
void some_method(FrameData<Projection> &m_data) {
    FrameData<Projection>::allocate<true>(m_data);
}
```

I'm ending up with some

```
error: reference to overloaded function could not be resolved; did you mean to call it?
```

- Is there some sort of analagous `.template` magic for `static` methods [like the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29754698/3814202)?
- Is the parameter `FrameData<Projection>` the problem?  It isn't fully defined yet?

Elsewhere in this world is technically in a source file with some explicit instantiations going on at the bottom, but I put this all in one file with the same errors.  Thank you for any insight, please refrain from shaming me on non-header templates.  It wasn't my choice.

Comment: Such API seems backwards to me, at least in choice of name. You cannot "allocate" an object you were passed by reference, it must already exist, i.e. be allocated.

Comment: Yeah I shortened the names and removed the majority of the definitions.  It's a wrapper struct that houses pointers to host / device data

Comment: This is fine except for the `::template` detail already answered. Maybe the real source has a good reason, but it's not clear why you're taking a parameter of the same type in a `static` function rather than using an implicit parameter: `template <bool devPtr> void allocate();`

Comment: Oh I see what you both are getting at.  I don't think I do have a justification for that.  I think it became this way because this was originally translated from `C`, so your standard `make_struct` type thing probably just got thrown into the class.  I completely agree though, I'll have to change that (now that I am actually able to compile it xD)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there some sort of analagous .template magic for static methods like the answer here?

Yes.

```
template <class Projection>
void some_method(FrameData<Projection> &m_data) {
    FrameData<Projection>::template allocate<true>(m_data);
}
```

Comment: AhHhHHHhhhh WOW I can't believe I never tried that. Thank you, will accept as soon as the 12 minute window has passed.