# Error using auto for return type of specialised template function

Tags: c++, c++11, template-specialization, auto

consider the following code snippet (simplified from a more complex code):

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

struct A{
    template<int S>
    void print(){ std::cout << S << std::endl; }
};

struct B{};

template <class T>
A foo(int);

template<>
A foo<B>(int){ return A{}; }

template<class T>
int bar(int){
  auto res = foo<T>(0);
  std::cout << typeid(res).name() << std::endl;
  res.print<5>();       // This line gives an error
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  bar<B>(0);
  return 0;
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f36c8155555c40f)

If I try to compile it (either with gcc or clang) it results in the following error:

```
main.cpp:21:16: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
   21 |   res.print<5>();
```

and I have to either:

- explicitly declare `res` as a `A_int` object
- call the method `print()` using the `template` keyword (`res.template print<5>();`)

in order to make this code compile.

I'm not really good in interpreting the Standard language, but as far as I understood the `template` keyword in a function call is needed when invoking a *template member function* on an object which type *explicitly depends on a template parameter* (see for instance [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840253/template-member-function-of-template-class-called-from-template-function)).

In this case, I didn't expect the keyword `template` to be needed since `res` should be an object of type `A`, which is not explicitly dependent on a template parameter (even if it's the result of a template function call).

Could someone help me understanding where I'm wrong, and when the `template` keyword is actually needed?

Thanks in advance, and apologise if this is a duplicate question, but I could not find anything specific for similar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all the compiler knows, somewhere in the program it has not yet seen there exists a specialization of `foo` for some `T` that returns something other than `A`. So it cannot assume `res` is always `A`. Therefore, the type of `res` does in fact depend on the template parameter `T`, and then `res.print` is a dependent name after all.

`template` keyword is then required to let the compiler know that the angle bracket after `print` is to be parsed as an angle bracket that forms part of a *template-id*, and not as a less-than operator.